# Array Sorting in an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have to sort the arrays of the "Key" in ascending order  and here's what I am doing .

Surprsingly the first array is getting sorted in descending order and the next two in ascending order . Whats the possible reason for this?

```
var MainObject4 = [{ "mainarray": [{ "Key": [9,768,78] },
{ "Key": [9,4,1] },{ "Key": [49,89,54] }]
}];

var first = MainObject4[0];
 Object.keys(MainObject4[0]).forEach(function (k) {
   first[k].forEach(function (j) { 
        Object.keys(j).forEach(function (g) {
                    j[g].sort();   
      },this);
  },this);
 },this);

 alert(JSON.stringify(MainObject4, 0, 4));
```

Expected output:

```
[9,78,768]
[1,4,9]
[49,54,89]
```

Output I am getting now:

```
[768,78,9]
[1,4,9]
[49,54,89]
```

Comment: `[768,78,9]` *is* sorted, lexicographically. Try passing a comparison function, e.g `function(x, y) { return x-y; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a function to compare sort parameters:

```js
var MainObject4 = [{
    "mainarray": [{
        "Key": [9, 768, 78]
    }, {
        "Key": [9, 4, 1]
    }, {
        "Key": [49, 89, 54]
    }]
}];

var first = MainObject4[0];

Object.keys(MainObject4[0]).forEach(function(k) {
    first[k].forEach(function(j) {
        Object.keys(j).forEach(function(g) {
            j[g].sort(function(a, b) {
             return a - b;
            });
        }, this);
    }, this);
}, this);

alert(JSON.stringify(MainObject4, 0, 4));
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [doc of `Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

If you want to compare numbers, you need to provide the comparison function, as said in the doc :

> To compare numbers instead of strings, the compare function can simply subtract b from a.

Answer (score 1):

```
var MainObject4 = [{ "mainarray": [
    { "Key": [9,768,78] },
    { "Key": [9,4,1] },
    { "Key": [49,89,54] }
  ]
}];


MainObject4[0].mainarray.forEach(function (j) { 
    Object.keys(j).forEach(function (g) {
                j[g].sort(function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        });   
    },this);
},this);

alert(JSON.stringify(MainObject4, 0, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of JavaScript's sort method takes by default unicode to compare the elements. For sorting numbers, you have to explicitly write a call back function to compare elements.  For ex

```js
var input = [1,20,2,12];
console.log(input.sort());// prints 1,12,2,20 
console.log(input.sort(function(a,b){
   return a-b;
}));// prints 1,2,12,20
```

So, You just need to add the compare function to your sort. That's all